# Air travel info between Andaman islands

Tags: air-travel, india, andaman-nicobar-islands, helicopters

What is the exact process of applying for helicopter ride between Port Blair and Havelock island? I've seen the application form [here](http://www.and.nic.in/transport/heliform.php) but I'd like to know the whole process. Did anyone here actually try it? Ideally I'd like info from someone with first-hand experience.

Since a helicopter ride is available in both directions, where would I apply for a ride when I'm on Havelock island already?

Since it's on the same note, same inquiry as above but for a seaplane.

[Helicopter Inter Island Schedule](http://www.and.nic.in/transport/helisch.php).

[Seaplane Inter Island Schedule](http://www.and.nic.in/transport/seaplane.php).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Helicopter rides aren't available between the islands. Since the guy there doesn't really speak English, I didn't understand whether it was because it was off season or it just doesn't fly anymore. (I did see the helicopter a few times while I was there, though.)

Seaplane is available for tourists and it costs 4100 rupees. You can only bring 5 kg of luggage with you or pay 97 rupees per kilo for excess luggage. (Side info - I tried sending my luggage by Makruz catamaran but they didn't want to take it if there was no passenger accompanying it.) Times of departure are not fixed but the seaplane leaves Havelock approximately at 8:00 and 13:00 every day.

I don't know about the schedule for other destinations and routes but since this one matches the one from the official website, I imagine that other info is correct [there](http://www.and.nic.in/transport/seaplane.php) as well.

It takes around half an hour to get to Port Blair and the view from the plane is amazing.

You book your flight in Village No. 1 half an hour before the departure. One unfortunate thing is that you can't take photographs from the plane or film the flight.

Comment: To paraphrase it, you can take photos but you aren't allowed. And I spent way too much money because of my excess luggage so I didn't have enough money for camera "permit".

Answer (score 2):

In early 2011, Pawan Hans launched the "Jal Hans" seaplane service between Port Blair and Havelock.  Not sure if it's still operating, but it's certainly worth giving them a ring.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jal_Hans

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, that's not a scheduled service but rather a charter service. There are no private airline service in Andaman and Nicobar Islands, and ones which are are operated by government-owned companies such as Air India. In case of the helicopters, it is operated by [Pawan Hans and according to their site](https://www.pawanhans.co.in/site/inner.aspx?status=3&menu_id=65), it's a charter service. This means that either you or someone on your behalf will need to file the papers to get the clearance for a charter flight. Check whether this is the case. You could probably get a tour agency to do it for you but it would cost you. Travel between the islands is usually done by ferries.

Comment: Do you maybe know whether I can file the papers once I get to Port Blair and not prior to that or should I contact the operator by email?

Comment: Ah this is a government-owned company, I highly doubt you'll get through to anyone by email. ('e-Governance' as they call it hasn't really taken off in India.) The paperwork probably won't be easy either since any sort of government forms in India are insane to deal with. As I see in the form you have linked to, you'll need a 'copy of pass' - this is because tourists are restricted to only visit a couple of islands. Your easier option would be perhaps see if there's a travel agency which arranges this, and whether it fits your budget.

Comment: But it says `Copy of Tribal Pass to be attached **in case of visit to the Southern Group of Islands viz. Car Nicobar, Teressa, Katchal and Kamorta**.`, if I want to go only from Port Blair to Havelock I guess I should be fine. I'll leave this one in case someone did use the charter service.